# Recovering Phone Data after Hardware Failure

Tags: data-recovery, broken-screen, google-pixel-2

I have a Pixel 2 phone running Android which appears to have a hardware failure. The screen only shows a multi-color static and is non-responsive. Occasionally I briefly see my normal lock screen, but the screen is non-responsive and goes back to static soon.

I need to get data from the device. Connecting via USB, running `adb devices` shows that no devices are detected.

How can I copy the storage from my phone to my computer, so that I can extract the desired data?

Comment: Phone is not unlocked, unfortunately

Comment: buy USB-C OTG Multiport HDMI Adapter and connect TV + mouse

Answer (score 3):

Copying data from a phone which is not detected by adb and has no screen info to tell what is happening is not going to take you very far from where you are.
Either try to get it to show on system somehow or get a working display to know what is happening on phone.